# Ruby: How to get name of parent module relative to self?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get the name of the parent module of my subclass:

```
module Special
  class BaseController
    def self.action
      puts Module.nesting.inspect # i want this to be relative to self
    end
  end
end

module Foobar
  class Controller < Special::BaseController
    action do
      # should print Foobar::Controller
    end
  end
end
```

How can I get the parent module of the subclass instead of the base class?

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being easier than I thought. Calling `self.to_s` will give you the full name (including modules). So you can grab the second to last one:

```
class_name = self.to_s.split('::')[-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that Ruby hasn't finished defining the module and class at the point you want to know about it. Once you've closed the definitions you could create an instance of it and find out:

```
irb(main):017:0> Foobar::Controller.new.class
Foobar::Controller < Special::BaseController
```

Then it's a case of doing a string split:

```
irb(main):033:0> Foobar::Controller.new.class.to_s.split('::')
[
    [0] "Foobar",
    [1] "Controller"
]
```

Comment: probably one can also use `name` instead of `to_s`